# App_Offline for Classic ASP Application

Tags: html, asp.net, iis, asp-classic, web

I have a classic ASP application hosted on IIS. I want the site to be inaccessible while I make some changes, and would like to implement something similar to app_offline that we use in ASP.NET.

But `app_offline.htm` doesn't seem to work for classic ASP

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many use one big-honking Include file with a set of functions used all over the site... at the top of this file, set a variable to indicate when maintenance is being performed or the site is otherwise unavailable, then test for the value before doing any other thing... if "down", [server.transfer or response.redirect](http://www.developer.com/net/asp/article.php/3299641/ServerTransfer-Vs-ResponseRedirect.htm) to your special "site unavailable" page.

```
Dim doMaintenance, RightNow, MaintenanceStart, MaintenanceEnd
doMaintenance = False

MaintenanceStart = CDate("6/18/2015 3:00pm")
MaintenanceEnd = CDate("6/18/2015 5:00pm")
RightNow = Now()

If RightNow > MaintenanceStart and RightNow < MaintenanceEnd Then doMaintenance = True

If doMaintenance Then Server.Transfer "otherpage.asp"
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

make additional web site, with the same binding like in primary web site and run it while you stop primary web site for maintenance. during all other time additional web site should be stopped.

> But app_offline.htm doesn't seem to work for classic ASP

ASP is not ASP.NET.

if application pool or web site stopped you cannot get any page from web sige.